# For loop over columns in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I would like to iterate over columns in dataframe and for every column if the number of NAs is bigger than 50% of all entries I would like to remove that column from the dataframe. So far I have something like this but it doesn't work:

```
for (i in names(df_r)) {
    if (sum(is.na(df_r[,i]))/length(df_r) > 0.5) {
        df_r <- df_r[, -i]
        }
    }
```

I am more of a python guy and I am learning R so I might be mixing syntax here.

Comment: just `df_r[colMeans(is.na(df_r)) < 0.5]`

Comment: also: please see how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610); that makes it a lot easier for other to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are much better off using more vector-based calculations vice the more literal `for` loop.

```
na50 <- sapply(df_r, function(x) sum(is.na(x))) / nrow(df_r)
df_r[na50 > 0.5] <- NULL
# or
df_r <- df_r[na50 <= 0.5]
```

Comment: Hmm i modified your solution to: na <- sapply(df_r, function(x) {sum(is.na(x)) / nrow(df_r)})
remove2 <- which(na>0.5)
df_r2 <- subset(df_r, select = -remove2), because otherwise I got the following error: Error in `[.data.table`(x, i, which = TRUE) : 
  i evaluates to a logical vector length 1371 but there are 1179 rows. Recycling of logical i is no longer allowed as it hides more bugs than is worth the rare convenience. Explicitly use rep(...,length=.N) if you really need to recycle.

Answer (score 3):

For loops in R are generally not very fast and should be avoided. In this case, you can use `dplyr` to make it fast and tidy:

```
library(dplyr)

df_r %>% 
  select_if(function(x) { ! sum(is.na(x)) / length(x) > 0.5 })
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `lapply` to loop over the data.frame columns:

```
DF <- data.frame(x = c(1, NA, 2), y = c("a", NA, NA))
DF[] <- lapply(DF, function(x) if (mean(is.na(x)) <= 0.5) x else NULL)
#   x
#1  1
#2 NA
#3  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
## for loop solution
for(i in names(dt))
{
    len <- nrow(dt)
    if(sum(is.na(dt[[i]])) > (len/2)) dt[[i]] <- NULL
    else next
}

## non for loop solution
cols <- colSums(is.na(dt))
cols <- names(cols[cols > (nrow(dt)/2)])
dt[[cols]] <- NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

It's basically one line:

```
df_r <- df_r[, apply(df_r, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(x) sum(is.na(x))/length(x) <= 0.5)]
```

`apply` applies the function (specified after `FUN =`)  to each column (specified by `MARGIN = 2`). The function checks whether the proportion of `NA`s is bigger smaller or equal to 0.5 and returns a logical vector. This vector then selects only the columns of `df_r` which have the small `NA` proportion.